# Download csv from website in R that does not contain a href (uses html button)

Tags: html, r, csv, download

I am trying to download a .csv from a website ("https://pollsports.com/data/").  I've viewed the HTML code, but there is no href to the .csv file.  Instead of a specific href for the .csv, the programmer used a html button (specifically button 3) to link the file ("poll-sports-download.csv").

In R, how can I reference the url to pull the specific .csv?  Or is there another way to go about this?  I was planning/trying to use download.file from the utils package.  Thus far, I have only been able to download the main HTML script for the page rather than the actual data.  Any and all help is appreciated!

## Download Poll Data

download.file(url, "../Data/Poll_Data_Download.csv")

Comment: The page just keeps loading for me without any data or csv file in the console.

Comment: The website does have some issues with that, but it has been working for me.  Is there anything I can provide to help make things more clear?